# Instantiating class from string wont really work in php

Tags: php

Ive just started learning namespaces. If I do this:

```
$a = new Devices\Desktop();
```

this works. But I have dynamic class names, so I have to do it from a variable.

```
$a = 'Devices\Desktop';
$a = new $a();
```

this is not working, although its the same. The class is not found. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072352/instantiating-class-by-string-using-php-5-3-namespaces

Comment: In what namespace is this code?

Comment: no, not possible duplicate, I read that, and didnt solve the problem.

Comment: judging on the answers to the other question, it looks like the code you posted is correct. the problem appears to lie elsewhere (perhaps the class is declared in a different namespace?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going out on a limb:

```
namespace Foo;

class Bar { }

new Bar;

$bar = 'Bar';
new $bar;
```

This won't work. String class names are always absolute, they're not resolved relative to the current namespace (because you can pass strings from one namespace to another, which should it resolve against then?). To make those two instantiations equivalent, you need to use a fully qualified class name:

```
$bar = 'Foo\Bar';
```

The `__NAMESPACE__` constant can be useful here:

```
$bar = __NAMESPACE__ . '\Bar';
```

Comment: I see. Is this in the official document?

Comment: Probably somewhere, yes. :-3