# PHP Namespaces what goes wrong?

Tags: php, namespaces

Hi guys so i'm trying to do the #3th example of  http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php.

This is my code:

```
include 'religions/norse/Ragnar.php';

use Religion\Person;

$name = 'Ragnar';

$character = new $name;

$character->introduce();
```

And for the Ragnar class:

```
namespace Religion\Person;

class Ragnar {

    public function introduce(){
        echo "My name is Ragnar, i'm a nord from Stokholm";
    }

}
```

But when I go to the website i'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Ragnar' not found in /home/test02/domains/t.test0.nl/public_html/namespaces/test.php on line 11
```

So it says that my class is not found but I don't know why...

Can someone help me with this??

Comment: Yes class not found! ofcourse _code not found_ in your question. Can you just add whats in `religions/norse/Ragnar.php`?

Comment: Ofcourse I can.

Comment: → http://stackoverflow.com/a/16653450/476

Comment: @deceze I'm using the __NAMESPACE__ . 'Ragnar' but that isn't working ether

Comment: Because you're not in the namespace `Religion\Person`, so `__NAMESPACE__` doesn't refer to `Religion\Person`. **You need to use the full name of the class**, `"Religion\Person\Ragnar"`, not just `"Ragnar"`.